# Mina 0.3.8 migration to Mina 1.2.3, NoMethodError: undefined method `isolate' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While migrating from mina 0.3.8 to 1.2.3 the below code is giving error as 
NoMethodError: undefined method `isolate' for main:Object

RUBY version - 2.6.2

```
task :deploy_all do
  isolate do
    domains.each do |domain|
      set :domain, domain
      invoke :deploy
      run!
    end
  end
end
```

I have checked the source code, could not find isolate method which is available on 0.3.8.

Any suggestion on how to fix the issue ?

Comment: In 0.3.8 [Mina::Helpers#isolate](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/v0.3.8/lib/mina/helpers.rb#L233) however it appears `1.0.0` is a complete rewrite with a new DSL [Migrating from 0.3.X to 1.0](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/master/docs/migrating.md) does not even mention `isolate`

Comment: @engineersmnky yes mina 1.0 has been rewritten, wondering why isolate has been removed.  Did that have the same support on a different method ?